# Continue a conversation after Browsing carousel in DialogFlow/Actions

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

So I have been experimenting with different Response types for DialogFlow through Actions: [Actions Responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses) and Webhook/Fulfillment.

And so far, I have been able to generate proper responses for types like List, Basic Card, Suggestion Chips successfully. What I need now is a list-based response that lets the user open a link in a browser when touched as well as "not" generate a chat bubble. "Browsing carousel" fits the criteria: [Browsing Carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel).

I have successfully created and simulated the output with 2 sample items. The issue is when the user wants to continue the conversation. As per the Guidance section in the help above, the browsing carousel:

> By default, the mic remains closed after a browse carousel is sent. If you want to continue the conversation afterwards, we strongly recommend adding suggestion chips below the carousel.

From this what I understood is that the user has to invoke the App again by saying "Ok Google, talk to [app]". This doesn't seem very user-friendly as the user expects to return back to the conversation she was having with the agent after she has looked through the links from the carousel. **Please note, I have simulated the flow using the Google Actions Simulator on Console.Actions page.**

As soon as I invoke the intent with the Browsing Carousel, it is shown to me with the sample Items. But when I enter/say the next command to continue the conversation, the agent simply returns with:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.

And the REQUEST/REQUEST window as well as the ERRORS/DEBUG are empty. I have logged calls to the Webhook and there is no call received.

*The question*: Is there a way to give the user the ability to browse an informative link from a response "list" (not Basic Card) and return to the conversation without ending it.

Here is the response for Browsing Carousel from RESPONSE window in Actions > Simulator (note I've removed non-relevant parts):

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[token info]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "You have the following 2 options:",
                "displayText": "You have the following 2 options:"
              }
            },
            {
              "carouselBrowse": {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "title": "Test 1",
                    "description": "Desc 2",
                    "image": {
                      "url": "[some url]"
                    },
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "url": "[some url]"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "Test 2",
                    "description": "Desc 2",
                    "image": {
                      "url": "[some url]"
                    },
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "url": "[some url]"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "Continue"
            },
            {
              "title": "End"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that the user stays in the conversation, but the mic will not be listening for the user's speech input. So you can say "OK Google" to activate the mic and then the user's speech will be processed and send directly to your conversation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I missed to do here was to test it on a device rather than using the Actions Simulator. On the device, it just turns off the mic and the conversation is not ended. This way if the user wishes to continue, he just needs to re-activate the mic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who are using the Simulator to test the Browsing Carousel and seeing that it stops responding after the output, please use a device instead to test it. When you use a device to render the output and use the Carousel response, it doesn't kill the conversation but turns off the mic. This is the intended behavior. One can introduce Suggestion chips to assist the user to continue the conversation.

**Updated**: Also make sure each Webhook Intent call has a proper response with Simple Response. As long as the response has required textual and audio information correctly setup, the Simulator will not fail.